# pjsip (pjsua) notification when remote user answers the call

Tags: sip, pjsip

I am trying to make a simple SIP user agent using https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject. I can succesfully connect to a sip server (Twilio) and place calls to PSTN numbers using the pjsua_* interface. This works fine.

What I would like now is to get a notification (through a callback or such) from pjsip when the user that I am calling answers the call.

I am using [on_call_state()](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__callback.htm#a8029ac58404a39067691a1530a2b585a) to get updates on the invite, but this goes through the same states

CALLING -> CONNECTING -> CONFIRMED -> DISCONNCTD

even if the user rejects the call. So I guess I am not looking at the right callback for this.

How can I definitely tell if the user has answered or rejected the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it is working this way. in on_call_state callback:

```
pjsua_call_info callInfo;
pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &callInfo);
pjsip_inv_state state = callInfo.state;
pjsip_status_code statusCode = callInfo.last_status;

switch (state) {
.....
case PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED:
    // remote party answered the call normally
    break;
case PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
    if (statusCode == PJSIP_SC_BUSY_HERE) {
       // rejected
    } else {
       // finished ok
    }
    break;
```

i reject call this way:

```
pj_status_t state;
int sendCode = PJSIP_SC_DECLINE;
try {
   state = pjsua_call_answer((pjsua_call_id) call_id, sendCode, nullptr, nullptr);
} catch (...) {
   return -1;
}
return state;
```

Comment: I think my problme was actually that I am using a Twilio test account and because of that, Twilio prepends an audio message saying that I should upgrade to a paid account. That is why the same flow is made even if the call is rejected. From the SIP perspective, the flow gets to confirmed because of the Twilio automated answer (to play the "please upgrade your account".